# Is there a way to drop database from aws instance when getting db error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to drop the database from one of the staging instance hosted in AWS. However I keep getting the following error when trying to execute `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails db:drop`:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table spree_preferences in model Spree::Preference.
Can not validate uniqueness for persisted record without primary key.
/home/deploy/.bundler/test_app/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:22:in `validate_each'
/home/deploy/.bundler/test_app/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.7/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `block in validate'
```

Is there a way I can solve this issue either by droping the table?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show what is there in the `schema.rb` file for `spree_preferences` table? It's possible that there is redundant data present in this table and/or in tables related to it, try deleting that and then try to run the `db:drop` command.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Figured out that when restoring the db someone accidentally left at the middle. Fixed it by re dumping the database.

Comment: Do you think I can add my comment as the answer?